# Downloading files with Mega API in .NET MAUI on Android

Tags: c#, android, maui, mega-api

I'm trying to download an image from a remote public Mega folder to an Android device using the Mega API in .NET MAUI.

This is the code:

```cs
namespace Junior_Jobs;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using CG.Web.MegaApiClient;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Android.OS;
using System;

public partial class Tryimportimage : ContentPage
{
    public Tryimportimage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MegaApiClient client = new MegaApiClient();
        client.LoginAnonymous();

        Uri fileLink = new Uri("https://mega.nz/file/W0UAgJaK#XOYyTETrIy8daz3_dw3fdh6Hh8EFEdrnbyoop1r9R6g");
        INode node = client.GetNodeFromLink(fileLink);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Downloading {node.Name}");
        client.DownloadFileAsync(fileLink, Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Downloads",node.Name));
        
        client.Logout();
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors at the moment, but the code doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I am trying to download a file that is not on already on my device,it is located in the mega directory online and i am trying to download it to the 'downloads' folder

Comment: fixed it,hope its understandable

Comment: Why are you trying to download the file in the constructor of a ContentPage? That cannot work. You're not awaiting the asynchronous Task of the download method `DownloadFileAsync()`, which cannot be done inside constructors, because they're synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should neither execute asynchronous code nor do any heavy lifting inside of constructors.

Secondly, you should `await` the `DownloadFileAsync()` method:

```cs
await client.DownloadFileAsync(fileLink, Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Downloads",node.Name));
```

Since this cannot be done inside the constructor, because constructors in C# cannot be asynchronous, you'll have to move the code into an `async` method instead:

```cs
namespace Junior_Jobs;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using CG.Web.MegaApiClient;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class Tryimportimage : ContentPage
{
    public Tryimportimage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task DownloadAsync()
    {
        MegaApiClient client = new MegaApiClient();
        client.LoginAnonymous();

        Uri fileLink = new Uri("https://mega.nz/file/W0UAgJaK#XOYyTETrIy8daz3_dw3fdh6Hh8EFEdrnbyoop1r9R6g");
        INode node = client.GetNodeFromLink(fileLink);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Downloading {node.Name}");
        await client.DownloadFileAsync(fileLink, Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Downloads",node.Name));
        
        client.Logout();
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate the `Tryimportimage` page and `await` the result, e.g. like this, depending on how you create your page:

```cs
public async Task OpenImportPageAsync()
{
    var page = new Tryimportimage();
    await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    await page.DownloadAsync();
}
```

Finally, downloading files and such should usually be delegated to service classes or ViewModels. It's not a common approach to do this directly in a View's code-behind.

You may want to read about [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios) using the ***async-await*** pattern.

Comment: i see,thanks for that,i have advanced,but now i recieve "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path '/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/SharedFile.jpg"

Comment: That's probably not a valid path or you don't have permissions to write data in that location. You can use the file system helpers for that or you need to request the necessary permissions.